# dcg parsing in random order

Tags: prolog, dcg

I have some text files which I would like to parse, however the order of for exemple stop and start could be different. Stop could appear first or last, this is a dummy exemple as there are multiple variables like stop,start ...

Exemple1.txt

> stop: 1
>
> start: 2

exemple2.txt

> start: 9
>
> stop: 4

I know how to parse start and stop when start is first and stop is second, however how would I do this when these are in random order.

```
parseStart(D) --> "start: " , integer(D).
parseStop(D) --> "stop: " , integer(D).
```

I recieve the to be parsed file from stdin , so I do
read_string to parse 1 line, turn that into char list and do phrase(parseStart(Startint),line1), same for line 2, however than I have to know the order which I don't.

Maybe I could do something like

```
parseBoth(StartInt,StopInt) --> parseStart(startInt) <|> parseStop(StopInt)
```

And do that two times and check if both are unified ? However this seems like a hack and I am wondering if there is a better way to do this ?

Edit: stop, start are just one of the many exemples, I have many dcg expressions that are in random order, how would I do this since trying every order would mean that I have to write 6! predicates for the 6 possible stop,start,end,time ... expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
parse(start(Start), stop(Stop)) -->
    first(Token),
    rest(Token, Start, Stop).

first(start) --> "start: ".
first(stop)  --> "stop: ".

rest(start, Start, Stop) -->
    integer(Start), stop(Stop).
rest(stop, Start, Stop) -->
    integer(Stop), start(Start).

start(Start) --> "start: " , integer(Start).
stop(Stop)   --> "stop: " , integer(Stop).
```

**Update** after the question edit.

If all lines of your text files have the format "keyword: integer", you could use:

```
parse_pairs([]) -->
    eos.
parse_pairs([Pair| Pairs]) -->
    parse_pair(Pair),
    parse_pairs(Pairs).

parse_pair(Key-Value) -->
    string(String), ": ", integer(Value), blanks,
    {atom_string(Key, String)}.
```

Sample call:

```
?- phrase(parse_pairs(Pairs), "start: 1\nstop: 2").
Pairs = [start-1, stop-2] .
```

Comment: This would work, however this was only a small proportion of the thing i have to parse, I have for exemple alse sentence: "also something", word: "a word", you get the idea I have like 6 of these things I have to parse, so using this wouldn't be ideal ?

Comment: Using your solution I would have if I have 6 of these dcg lines which can all be in random order, I would have to write 6! = 720 predicates, which doesn't seem like a good solution.

Comment: @swaffelay Is best if you add those details to the question itself.

Comment: edited the question, however in the first line of the questionI stated "this is a dummy exemple as there are multiple variables like stop,start ..." , But made it more clear, thx for the reply

Comment: @swaffelay Add a second suggestion to my answer.